# Prove $a\sim Uniform_{[0,1)}\implies \lfloor an\rfloor\sim Uniform_{\{0,...,n-1\}}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, proof-writing

Suppose $a$ is a r.v. sampled from uniform distribution on $[0,1)$. Prove that the r.v.
$$
b=\lfloor an\rfloor,\qquad \text{where $n> 0$ is integer }
$$
is distributed uniformly over  $\{0,...,n-1\}$.

intuitively this holds, I could imagine groups of values in $[0,1)$ of same size being mapped to each value in $\{0,...,n-1\}$ but I have no idea how to prove it ...

Comment: For any bounded function $f:\mathbb{Z}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,

\begin{align}
E[f(Y)]&=\int^1_0 f(\lfloor an\rfloor]\,da=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\int_{[\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})}f(\lfloor an\rfloor)\,da\\
&=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}f(k)\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}

this shows that $P[Y=k]=\frac1n$ for $0\leq k<n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be readily shown directly.

Let $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$.
We can get rid of the floor function by utilizing the following equivalency:
$$
\lfloor an \rfloor \leq k \iff an < k+1.
$$

Now we can calculate the cdf of our random variable:
$$
P(\lfloor an \rfloor \leq k ) = P(a < (k+1)/n) = (k+1)/n,
$$

which we recognize as the cdf of the discrete uniform on $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Also the comment by @Mittens gave me this idea

for $k\in\{0,...,n-1\}$
$$
\newcommand{\p}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{Pr\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\floor}[1]{\lfloor #1 \rfloor}
\newcommand{\bp}[1]{\left[ #1 \right)}
\prob{\floor{an}=k}=\prob{an\in [k,k+1)}\\
=\prob{a\in \bp{\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n}}}\\
=\p{\frac{k+1}{n}-\frac{k}{n}} \Big/ 1\\
= \frac{1}{n}
$$
because size of $[0,1)$ is $1$.